# View is not showing up on iPhone simulator but showing on actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, simulator

I'm trying to add a view with an image and label on it. I tested it on my iPhone 5s device and it works. But when I tried to run it on the iPhone 6 simulator it didn't show up. Same with iPhone 5s simulator, it didn't show up too.

Have you experienced this too?

Thank you.

P.S. I didnt add constraints for now on the uiView I've added, just want to test first if it shows up. but the rest have constraints.

See screenshot below

[image: From iPhone 5s device]

[image: From iPhone 5s simulator]

Comment: Be clear on asking questions attach some screehsot . Are you using autolayout?. May be  constraints are not set up properly if you re using autolayout

Comment: Hi sorry..
Yeah Im using autolayout and there's a previous constraints set already.. I just added a new uiview.

Comment: Are you asking if anyone else has experienced this? or Is this currently happening and you are trying to fix it?

Comment: probably you are using size classes for iPhone 5S. Try running your project on iPhone 5 simulator and you'll see your layout.  You need to set proper constraints to make your UI to fit any layout. I suggest you to learn more on auto layouts. Your UIView will probably not show up if you haven't added any constraints yet.

Comment: Even I place it anywhere on the view, it doesn't show. I also tried to add constraints to it before.. but still not showing on simulator..

Okay, i'll try to run it on iPhone 5 simulator. thanks @sleepwalkerfx :)

Comment: @shana27 Just saw your edit. if you are getting different results with iPhone 5 or 5S simulator and real iPhone 5s device, cause of the issue may not be indeed constraints. However try to add proper constraint anyway before testing.

Comment: Hi @sleepwalkerfx I just tried to run it on iPhone 5 simulator.. it didn't show up too.

Comment: @shana27 are the iOS versions same between simulator and iphone ?

Comment: Yes .. ios 10.0 @sleepwalkerfx

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers. I've already figured it out.
I just add a compact, regular size on its constraints (see screenshot)

[image: screenshot1]